# errors in Grails service

Tags: grails

i'm new to Grails i'm using **Grails 2.5.1** , i'm creating a service but when i call this service i get the bellow errors :

```
Class:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyExceptionMessage:No such property: flash for class: com.sherif.UtilsService Possible solutions: class
```

and

```
Class:groovy.lang.MissingMethodExceptionMessage:No signature of method: com.sherif.UtilsService.render() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[view:forget]] Possible solutions: every(), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), every(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

here is my service :

```
class UtilsService {

def sendPassword(params) {

    def enteredCeredintials = User.findByEmail(params?.email)
    if (enteredCeredintials?.email==null) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'user.email.notfound', args: [params?.email])

    }
    else {
        flash.message = message(code: 'user.passwordSent', args: [params?.email])
        }
 render (view: "forget")
}
}
```

what may caused these errors ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flash` is temporary storage used in the web tier - it's one of the implicit variables that's available in controllers, along with `request`, `response`, `session`, etc. But it's not available in services - there are no implicit variables in services.

Ideally you should keep each tier separate. Services shouldn't work with or be aware of the web tier - they're helper classes that use business logic to perform various tasks, work with the database, etc. They're called by controllers, but shouldn't be polluted with web tier concepts.

To fix this, extract out the logic that is independent of the web tier and do that work in the service. Then return whatever data you need to render the view in the controller, and in this case to additionally store some data in `flash` scope.